# Ruby Testing: Testing for the Absence of a Method

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, macruby

In rspec and similar testing frameworks, how does one test for the absence of a method?

I've just started fiddling with rspec and bacon (a simplified version of rspec.) I wanted to define test that would confirm that a class only allows read access to an instance variable. So I want a class that looks like:

```
class Alpha
  attr_reader :readOnly

  #... some methods

end
```

I am rather stumped:

```
  it "will provide read-only access to the readOnly variable" do
    # now what???
  end
```

I don't see how the various types of provided test can test for the absence of the accessor method. I'm a noob in ruby and ruby testing so I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: As a side note, Ruby is snake-cased by convention.  Underscores separate words in method and variable names.

Comment: Yes, I know but I'm working a lot in Objective-C with MacRuby so I tend to use camelCase out of habit. I'll try to remember not to do so in my post because I know how much not following conventions makes code hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, you can check if an object responds to a method with `obj.respond_to?(:method_name)`, so with rspec, you can use:

```
Alpha.new.should_not respond_to(:readOnly=)
```

Alternatively, since classes could override the `respond_to?` method, you can be stricter and make sure that there is no assignment method by actually calling it and asserting that it raises:

```
expect { Alpha.new.readOnly = 'foo' }.to raise_error(NoMethodError)
```

See [RSpec Expectations](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-6/dir/built-in-matchers) for reference.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it, in classic duck typing fashion. For posterity, it's also possible to check for inclusion in the object's `methods` array: `Alpha.new.methods.include?(:readOnly=)`

Comment: Ah, yes, I was making this to hard. For some reason, I assumed that ruby lacked a "responds_to_ like function owing to duck typing. Most non-static typed languages have such a function and I should have known ruby would as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `respond_to?`, as in `some_object.respond_to? :some_method`.